# boostrap-vue when using tabs in modal it is not working properly

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

If you put b-tabs inside of a modal, upon opening the modal for the first time everything works fine, but if you close the modal and reopen it, then the tabs don't work, it will be stuck on the content of the first tab, and switching tabs will not have any effect, instead the content of the first tab will remain visible. Reloading the page is the only way to get it to work again.

Visit https://jsfiddle.net/gh9y7zLs/2/ to reproduce the problem

```
    <div id='app'>
<div>
    <b-button v-b-modal.modal1>
      Launch demo modal
    </b-button>

    <!-- Modal Component -->
    <b-modal
      id="modal1"
      title="BootstrapVue" >
      <b-tabs content-class="mt-3" v-model="tabIndex">
        <b-tab
          title="first"
          active
        >
          I'm the first fading tab

          <b-button v-b-modal.modal1 @click="next()">
            Next
          </b-button>
        </b-tab>
        <b-tab title="second">
          <p>
            I'm the second tab content
          </p>
        </b-tab>
        <b-tab
          title="disabled"
          disabled
        >
          <p>
            Disabled tab!
          </p>
        </b-tab>
      </b-tabs>
    </b-modal>

  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone have a solution ?

Comment: For some reason it does seem to work with Vue.js version 2.5.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in the latest release coming out soon (v2.0.0-rc.23)

Comment: 2.0.0-rc.24 has just been released with a few additional fixes for `b-tabs`